# Open SuSE MicroOS Add Disk

Tags: opensuse

I am working on OpenSuse MicroOS using their pre-configured HyperV disk. I got it up and running successfully, but after trying to install a few containers I ran out of space. I stopped the VM and added another disk, but am not sure what to do now. I have a basic understanding of LVM, but that doesn't appear to be what MicroOS uses. Can anyone tell me how to extend the /var partition (I believe that's the correct one?). Or point me to some documentation on how to do it?

Comment: What is the result of commands: `vgs`, `lvs`, `pvs` (as `root`)? How is visible the new disk in OS?

Comment: Hi Romeo, none of those commands exist. I did find a workaround where I can expand the disk they provided and that seems to be working well. However I'm not sure if that's the correct way.

Comment: You can add the steps as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer, as commented above you can simply expand the provided disk using HyperV and MicroOS seems to grow the partition correctly. Whether this is the "correct" way or not, I'm not sure.